# MYSQL Select; I cannot figure out how to exclude rows based on a different column value

Tags: php, mysql

Table:

id     value
100      1
101      1
102      1
102      0
103      1

I want the selection to return id's 100,101,103; that is, if the same id has two rows, one with value=1 and a second with value=0, I want to exclude it.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: How in the world could an ID appear twice O_O ?

Comment: You should re-design your database to aboid duplicate of ID's.

Comment: Sorry, very misleading!  I was trying to greatly simplify a table, the "id" column is really a foreign key.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
Select id From table Group By id Having count(*) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM
table 
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Could use the `having` MySQL construct:

```
SELECT id, count(*) AS tehCount FROM table GROUP BY id HAVING tehCount = 1;
```

Comment: Which solution did you end up implementing?